# Access dvcs repository from python web app - handle concurrent edits and commits

Tags: python, web-applications, version-control, locking, dvcs

We are working on a web app using django that will allow for modification of files which are stored in a vcs repo (currently git).

Writing to the file in the local workspace will be done as long as edit runs in browser.
Adding/committing will happen when user is finished with editing (save) or after a given time lapse.

Because there will be parallel web sessions running, I am concerned by the concurrent access to the versioned files :

- when reading / writing in the local workspace
- as we want commit messages to contain messages specific to each file's modification, we also need some kind of lock to prevent `add` - `commit` operations to interlace.

So I guess we should use some kind of locking and am looking for a mechanism which is robust and compatible with the web app architecture :

- I read about flocks, but I guess it is not adapted to a stateless application; I probably cannot hold a filehandle easily, can I ?
- I could create some kinds of `filename.ext.lock` files to programmatically handle mutual access exclusion
- Or I could have a dedicated table in db for the same goal
- Other solution would be to delegate vcs accesses (file and repo) to a dedicated process, but I couldn't find anything yet; searching for `git daemon` only return results that deal with operating on whole repos for clone / push / pull / ..., not for file level operations

Do you see other means than the ones above ? 
Do you know of aspects we should specially take care of ?

Comment: Locking is a bad idea. Use one workspace per client (probably tricky to implement and scale) or use low-level commands/APIs to interact with Git. Regardless there will be races between clients, but you can be optimistic and retry operations if they fail because of interlacing commits.

Comment: I searched for 'low level git' commands, very instructive, thanks for pointing it. I then found in the GitPython two util functions : [BlockingLockFile](http://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/reference.html#git.util.BlockingLockFile) and [LockFile](http://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/reference.html#git.util.LockFile) that seem really attractive to me but, well, not widely used ;) Anyway, I still face the interrogation why locking is a bad idea here; can anyone help me understand ?

Comment: Locking on a single machine certainly works if Git transactions can take place within the same request handler (i.e. you don't have to rely on keeping state), but with increased load it won't scale as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Magnus Bäck. Unlike SVN you can create different copies of git-repos and merge them into one another without a server, just on your local machine. So you can have a bunch of copies of the same repository and each client/process gets its own folder. You can delete and copy them when you need more or less.

Also you can do

```
git remote add local_original file:///var/git/project.git
```

[(source)](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/git-and-remote-repositories/)

in each copy and use this for

```
git push local_original
```

to push the changes to this local repository to synchronize all users working on it.

I would go in favor of copying because it can scale better than locks. 
Here is something that I implemented that does not have to scale but that I would implement with copying if it had to: https://github.com/niccokunzmann/gh-pages-edit

Comment: I see in the cloning-merging the drawback of conflict resolution which would make it more complex to maintain; where is the technical difficulty of having non blocking locks, resulting in pages for the user like 'Sorry, file is being edited, try again later'?

Comment: Mutual exclusion in distributed or parallel systems is also not too trivial. Which algorithm would you use? Does is scale over different servers/machines? I do not now your use case. You can also answer your question and argue in favor of mutual exclusion. I recommend modifying the question a bit so that people are more encouraged to post a different answer than mine. "access repository" "concurrent edit"... The problem with referring to git is that 1. people who like git do not like locks 2. people who do not like git do not answer.